# Understanding how the tension in a string affects nodes and anitinodes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, harmonic-oscillator, superposition, string

I was given a question to solve where theres a vibrating oscillator attached to a string which goes over a pulley and has a mass hanging on it. I was told that the vibrator has a single frequency, and for masses of 16kg and 25kg standing waves are observed.

I want to know why the heavier object will be at a lower mode.

Comment: -1. No research effort. Try googling "standing waves on string".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tension in a string affects the speed of propagation of a wave: the higher the tension, the higher the wave speed.

$$c=\sqrt {\frac {T}{\rho}}$$

(c=speed, T=tension, $\rho $=mass per unit length). At a given frequency, higher speed means longer wavelength - and longer wavelength means fewer half wavelengths fit in the same length of string.

Comment: Why does a higher speed mean longer wavelengths?

Comment: "At a given frequency", higher speed means longer wavelength. This is because the wave speed is one wavelength per period, in other words, $c = \lambda ~ f.$ So if you hold frequency constant, then it's a linear relationship between $c$ and $\lambda.$ Your vibrator fixes the frequency to be just one value and therefore this is the right way to think about the problem.

Comment: In very technical terms, a driven oscillator with linear losses $\ddot y + \lambda \dot y + k y = g(t)$ can be viewed in Fourier space where $(-\omega^2 + i\lambda \omega + k) y[\omega] = g[\omega]$ and if $g$ is sharply peaked at some frequency then the resulting $y$ must also be sharply peaked at that frequency. The prefactor just says "this thing gets large if that frequency happens to be near the resonant frequency $\sqrt k$," but it doesn't change that "peaked" result. So though the system is complicated, the resonator really *does* set the frequency that the string will oscillate.

Comment: In the time it takes to complete one oscillation, a faster wave will have traveled further- so the waveform will be stretched more. That makes the wavelength proportional to the velocity - in fact  $\lambda=\frac {c}{f} $ and resonance occurs when an integer number of half-wavelengths fits between the supports of the string.

Answer (score 0):

@Floris completely answered your question. I wanted to chime in to help you visualize a bit what is going on.

First of the standing waves occur because there is a transmitted wave moving away from the shaker and then there is a reflected wave from the pulley. If one wave has amplitude $A$ and the other amplitude $B$ then the wave function is

$$ y(x,t)  = A \sin \left( \omega \left( t + \frac{x}{c} \right) \right)  + B \sin \left( \omega \left( t - \frac{x}{c} \right) \right)$$

where $\omega$ is the frequency of oscillation (in rad/s) and $c$ the wave propagation speed. The above is re-arranged as:

$$ y(x,t) = (A-B) \sin\left( \frac{\omega x}{c} \right) \cos(\omega t) + (A+B) \cos\left( \frac{\omega x}{c} \right) \sin(\omega t)$$

The above is *two* standing waves at 90° phase difference, one with amplitude $A-B$ and the other with $A+B$. The situation is characterized by the [*standing wave ratio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave_ratio) $${\rm SWR} = \frac{A-B}{A+B}$$

If there is imperfect reflection then there aren't distinct nodes, but almost nodes (with small but not zero magnitude). The wave shape will resemble the pictures in the referenced wikipedia page above.

> [image]

Why is this important? Well in an experiment the applied tension (weights added) will not only change the wave propagation speed $c =\sqrt{ \frac{T}{\rho}}$ but also the reflectivity (or the standing wave ratio). So you might not get *exactly* what you expect from the experiment.